# How can I change the color of when having disabled attribute using css?

Tags: css, angularjs

I need to change the color of this button `<md-button class="md-fab">` only when it is enabled

so I can do that

```
.md-fab{
     background-color: orange !important; 
}
```

but that make the button color 'orange' always, 
I want to keep the color gray when the button is disabled

how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector for disabled elements, like this:

```
.md-fab:disabled {
    background-color: gray !important; 
}
```

Then your button will be gray if disabled, and orange if enabled.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    .md-fab:disabled{
        background-color: inherit !important; 
    }
```

in css

Answer (score 0):

Css give you [**attribute selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) for the task.

```
.md-fab:disabled{
   background-color: gray !important; 
}
```

or

```
.md-fab[disabled]{
   background-color: gray !important; 
}
```

Here is [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/imayazshah/anxth0xj/)